# How do I show text in text field?

Tags: html, struts

I used `<s:iterator>` tag to display  `checkboxs` and `text fields`:

```
<s:iterator value="paramMapSimple" var="param" status="iteratorStatus">
<tr>
<td>
  <input type="checkbox" name="params" key_id="<s:property value="#iteratorStatus.index "/>" value = "<s:property value="#param.key "/>"
  <s:iterator value="params" var="app">
  <s:if test="#app.substring(0,1)==#param.key">
    checked
  </s:if>
</s:iterator>/>
</td>

<td>
  <input type="text" text_id="<s:property value="#iteratorStatus.index "/>" >
</td>
</tr>
```

`params` of type `String[]` stores the `index` and `input text` which have been checked, e.g., if the first and second checkboxes are checked, and the user input `"paramName1"` and `"paramName2"` in the `text field`, respectively, then `params` is: `{1@paramName1, 2@paramName2}`, and if the user check a `checkbox` but doesn't input anything, then default value will be stored, e.g., if the first and second checkboxes are checked, and the user only input `"paramName1"` for the first `checkbox`, then `params` is: `{1@paramName1, 2@defaultParamName2}`.
What I want is: if a `checkbox` is checked, then the `text field` shows the text input by the user (if the user doesn't input, shows the default value), otherwise, shows the default value.

Comment: then you need a placeholder for the text in input?

Answer (score 0):

In HTML, you can actually use a `textarea`:

For example:

```
<textarea rows="4" cols="50">
The text you want to put here!
</textarea>
```

You can refer to [HTML textarea tag](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_textarea.asp)

---

You can also use a `placeholder`:

For example:

```
<form action="submit.php">
  <label for="phone">Enter a phone number:</label><br><br>
  <input type="tel" id="phone" name="phone" placeholder="123-45-678"
  pattern="[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{3}"><br><br>
  <small>Format: 123-45-678</small><br><br>
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

This will generate a **hint text** in the textbox!

You can refer more at [HTML input placeholder](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_placeholder.asp)